# C integer overflow behaviour when assigning to larger-width integers

Tags: c, casting, integer, overflow, integer-overflow

If I execute the following code in C:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t a = 4000;
uint16_t b = 8000;

int32_t c = a - b;

printf("%d", c);
```

It correctly prints '-4000' as the result.  However, I'm a little confused: shouldn't there be an arithmetic overflow when subtracting a larger unsigned integer from the other?  What casting rules are at play here?  This question seems a bit noobish, so any references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is actually somewhat complicated. Operands of arithmetic expressions are converted using specific rules that you can see in Section 3.2.1.5 of the [Standard (C89)](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt). In your case, the answer depends on what the type `uint16_t` is. If it is smaller than `int`, say `short int`, then the operands are converted to `int` and you get -4000, but on a 16-bit system, `uint16_t` could be `unsigned int` and conversion to a signed type would not happen automatically.

Comment: My reference is of course to the old standard. See tgamblin's response for C99. Though they say the same thing.

Comment: 3.2.1.5 is for double/float/int/etc conversions.  He's looking for integral (long/int/char/short/etc) promotions which is in 3.2.1.1 of that version of the standard.  It's in 6.3.1.1 in the newer standard I linked to above.

Comment: He might also want 3.2.1.2 too (signed/unsigned ints)

Comment: Section 3.2.1.5 covers integer conversions too.

Comment: oh hm so it does.  I guess it's got rules for longs and such too.  There's an index item that points you to 3.2.1.1 for integral promotions.

Comment: Alright, so what if we extend the example to two uint32_t and one int64_t, assuming 32-bit int width?

Comment: In that case, the subtraction is unsigned and overflows.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that these are all promoted to `int` during the subtraction.  For the long answer, look at section 6.3.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), where it talks about **integer promotions** in arithmetic expressions.  Relevant language from the standard:

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of
>   the original type, the value is
>   converted to an **`int`**;  otherwise, it is
>   converted to an **`unsigned int`**. These
>   are called the *integer  promotions*.
>   All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.

The details are in there, too, but they get pretty nasty.

Answer (score 1):

Both operands are promoted to `int32_t` during the subtraction. If the result had been larger than the maximum value for `int32_t` you would've seen overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is, in fact, an overflow but C does not tell you.

The overflow leaves a value that happens to be -4000 when interpreted as a signed integer. This works as designed on 2's complement machines.

Try to interpret the result as unsigned, and you'll notice that (u1-u2) evaluates to some seemingly unrelated number when u1 < u2.